# How to use Wildcard certificates from Let’s Encrypt with cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, amazon-eks, cert-manager

I Created two files, one is for ClusterIssuer and the Second is for Certificate.
My Domain is an example.com and I need to create a new subdomain with wildcard `*.testing.example.com` and I already created an entry in Route53 called `*.testing.example.com` with A record and mapped with nlb.

Below are my profile and which good to me, but I am getting error **" msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="DNS record for \"testing.example.com\" not yet propagated"**

ClusterIssuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: devops@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
            name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    # example: cross-account zone management for example.com
    # this solver uses ambient credentials (i.e. inferred from the environment or EC2 Metadata Service)
    # to assume a role in a different account
    - selector:
        dnsZones:
          - "example.com"
      dns01:
        route53:
          region: ap-south-1
          hostedZoneID: 71MYVttggee
          role: arn:aws:iam::123456:role/dns-manager
```

```
Certificate.yaml

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-cert
spec:
  secretName: acme-crt
  issuerRef:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: testing.example.com
  dnsNames:
    - '*.testing.example.com'
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: route53
      domains:
        - '*.testing.example.com'
```

Comment: Do you see the verification records created in your Zone? Check in the R53 console.

Comment: yes, verification records (TXT) created in my Zone?

Comment: Then you just have to wait a while for them to propagate, as the log says.

Comment: Any specific timing? How much time generally it takes?

Comment: It depends on your zone TTLs, but usually in the 30-60 minute range.

Comment: @me25 did waiting solve the issue?

Comment: yes, the problem is solved , these files are 100 correct . Problem with my DNS ZONE

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct, you just need to wait for DNS propagation so that the verification records can be checked by LetsEncrypt.

Comment: but log is saying ""msg"="propagation check failed"" ? then still I need to wait?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the method of DNS-01 for verification auth.

You can use the `issuer`

https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/

however, you also have to create one another YAML for certificate

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: le-crt
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret
  issuerRef: 
    kind: Issuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: "*.example.in"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.example.in"
```

above yaml certificate will point to issuer that you created and as you get the certificate it will be get stored into the kubernetes secret name as : `tls-secret`

You can inject or use this secret on the `ingress`.

Also if you are facing the **403** error of `CAA` record please add the CAA record in the `DNS zone` first same we add the `A` or `CNAME` record.

For more ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476135/5525824