# Generate wildcard certificate on Kubernetes cluster with DigitalOcean for my Nginx-Ingress

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I followed this DigitalOcean guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes, and I came across something quite strange. When in the hostnames I set a wildcard, then `letsencrypt` fails in issuing a new certificate. While when I only set defined sub-domains, then it works perfectly.

This is my "working" configuration for the domain and its api (and this one works perfectly):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    - api.example.com
    secretName: my-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-frontend
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-api
          servicePort: 80
```

And this is, instead, the wildcard certificate I'm trying to issue, but that fails to do leaving the message "Issuing".

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    - *.example.com
    secretName: my-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-frontend
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-api
          servicePort: 80
```

The only difference is the second line of the hosts. Is there a trivial well known solution I am not aware of? I am new to Kubernetes, but not to DevOps.

Comment: Hello, the [documentation](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#does-let-s-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates) states that to generate `wildcard` certificate you'll need to use `DNS-01` challenge instead of  `HTTP-01` (used in the link). Here you find some documentation that should help you: https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/

Comment: It was that! Sorry it took me some time, but I had to rebuild the whole system and test it properly. If you want you can post it as an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Your question contains the same source code twice. I presume the second code should show the configuration for your certificate. Can you please update your question so that it will become more helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating wildcard certificate with `cert-manager` (`letsencrypt`) requires the usage of `DNS-01` challenge instead of `HTTP-01` [used in the link from the question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes):

> #### Does Let’s Encrypt issue wildcard certificates?
>
> Yes. Wildcard issuance must be done via ACMEv2 using the DNS-01 challenge. See [this post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578) for more technical information.

There is a documentation about generating the `wildcard` certificate with `cert-manager`:

- *[Cert-manager.io: Docs: Configuration: ACME: DNS-01](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/)*

---

From the perspective of DigialOcean, there is a guide specifically targeted at it:

> This provider uses a Kubernetes `Secret` resource to work. In the following
> example, the `Secret` will have to be named `digitalocean-dns` and have a
> sub-key `access-token` with the token in it. For example:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Secret
> metadata:
>   name: digitalocean-dns
>   namespace: cert-manager
> data:
>   # insert your DO access token here
>   access-token: "base64 encoded access-token here"
> ```
>
> The access token must have write access.
>
> To create a Personal Access Token, see [DigitalOcean documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/api/create-personal-access-token).
>
> Handy direct link: https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/api/tokens/new
>
> To encode your access token into base64, you can use the following
>
> ```sh
> echo -n 'your-access-token' | base64 -w 0
> ```
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
> kind: Issuer
> metadata:
>   name: example-issuer
> spec:
>   acme:
>     ...
>     solvers:
>     - dns01:
>         digitalocean:
>           tokenSecretRef:
>             name: digitalocean-dns
>             key: access-token
> ```
>
> -- *[Cert-manager.io: Docs: Configuration: ACME: DNS-01: Digitalocean](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/digitalocean/)*

---

I'd reckon this additional resources could also help:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Wilcard SSL certificate with subdomain redirect in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613842/wildcard-ssl-certificate-with-subdomain-redirect-in-kubernetes)*
- *[Itnext.io: Using wildcard certificates with cert-manager in Kubernetes](https://itnext.io/using-wildcard-certificates-with-cert-manager-in-kubernetes-and-replicating-across-all-namespaces-5ed1ea30bb93)*

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard cert require `DNS-01` method

**Note** : You might require to first add the CAA record in your DNS.

CAA record can get added into DNS zone

**example** :

```
            Type       Value

devops.in   CAA       0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
```

get details from : https://sslmate.com/caa/

First, you have to create the secret for storing the `access key` using the command

```
kubectl create secret generic route53-secret --from-literal=secret-access-key="skjdflk4598sf/dkfj490jdfg/dlfjk59lkj"
```

Here sharing the example `issuer.yaml`

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: test123@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - selector:
        dnsZones:
          - "devops.in"
      dns01:
        route53:
          region: us-east-1
          hostedZoneID: Z2152140EXAMPLE
          accessKeyID: AKIA5A5D7EXAMPLE
          secretAccessKeySecretRef:
            name: route53-secret
            key: secret-access-key
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: le-crt
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret
  issuerRef: 
    kind: Issuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: "*.devops.in"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.devops.in"
```

Also, make sure your user has necessary permission to manage the `Route53`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "route53:GetChange",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::change/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "route53:ListHostedZonesByName",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```